# Is it normal to see the Microsoft Edge recent call stack values become undefined in the next?

Tags: javascript, debugging, microsoft-edge

This is my call stack screen shot:

[image]

In the next call I get all the arguments undefined:

[image]

How is this possible, a simple function call loosing arguments.

Comment: I'm an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team, and have forwarded this question to one of our F12 team members.

Comment: @Iman do you have a repro that's publically accessible or that you could share? We shouldn't be loosing arguments as you step but to help reduce the issue it would be great to have a repro. Thanks!

Comment: @AndySterland unfortunately I don't have the permission to share this code with anyone is there an other way I can send you the data you are looking for?